# control of LEDs with 16bit PWM with protocol DMX512/1990 using only one DMX address

Tags: led, 16-bit, dmx512

I have received DMX LED drivers from a company called G&G in China, unfortunately with extremely poor documentation. This is how the drivers look like, under the picture are the specs:

[image]

The model I received is on the left, specs:

- 4 channel LED driver
- DMX512 3-pin interface (D+, D-, GND)
- 12-36V input
- 700mA constant-current driver
- "The refresh rate reaches 3980 Hz while guaranteeing the gray scale up to 65536"

With this information I was thinking that this was a 16bit DMX device (65536 levels)

The manufacturer says that these drivers will accept only 4 DMX addresses.

In my experience, to have 16bit control over LED channels, one should use two DMX addresses per channel, 256 values + 256 fine-tuning values

However, the manufacturer says that this is only true for an old version of the DMX protocol and that I should be able to control the drivers in 16 bit per channel using only one DMX address per channel, i.e. 4 DMX addresses per driver (the driver has 4 channels)

Has anyone here ever experienced the possibility of having 16bit control via the DMX protocol, using only one DMX address per channel?